# How can control button Text Size in customized Button class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-button

I've some buttons in my activity that inflate from a custom class that make the button exact square and fit them in parent depend on screen size and it work's fine :

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size); // make it square

}
}
```

and here my inflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Button newGuessButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, currentTableRow, false); 
currentView.addView(newGuessButton);
```

and layout.xml:

```
<my.package.name.MyButton
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newButton"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="100"/>
```

and my question is how can set text size in my button to change the default size if I want. I think I've to set it before add it as a view but I don't know HOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to set text size you can use attribute

```
android:textSize
```

or use method

```
Button.setTextSize()
```

If you want to fit text inside button you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: !! D , of course that I have to Button.setTextSize() but set it to what size?

Comment: Check  the link I send above

Comment: I accepted your answer and voted it up,thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, but I found an ***unofficial*** way:As I told, my customize class (at end) make me some button that fill the parent screen, and depend on how many of it that I want to create in a row and the width size or height size of screen(we need smaller one) we can find the size nearest number to that one to will create like this:(I want to create 5 square buttons in a row )

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int tempSize = width / 5;// (5: number of buttons)
float ff = (float) ((tempSize * 0.4) / (scale));// (0.4: for example)
....
newGuessButton.setTextSize(ff);
currentView.addView(newGuessButton);
```